# Unable to load resource 404 in spring mvc + hibernate + maven

Tags: spring-mvc

Unable to load resource 404 in spring mvc + hibernate + maven

**home.jsp**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
     <html lang="en-US">
        <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
        <title> Spring MVC 4 REST + AngularJS </title>
         <%-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url   value="resources/css/style.css"/>" /> --%>
          <link href="<c:url value="/aresources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
           </head>
           <body ng-app="myApp">
             <div ng-controller="PersonController as personCtrl">
                <h1> Spring MVC 4 REST + AngularJS </h1>
                  <form name="personForm" method="POST">
                <table>
                  <tr><td colspan="2">
                    <div ng-if="personCtrl.flag != 'edit'">
                     <h3> Add New Person </h3> 
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="personCtrl.flag == 'edit'">
                      <h3> Update Person for ID: {{ personCtrl.person.pid }} </h3> 
                      </div> </td>
                      </tr>
                    <tr>
                   <td>Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="personCtrl.person.name" required/> 
                  <span ng-show="personForm.name.$error.required" class="msg-val">Name is required.</span> </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                  <td>Location: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="personCtrl.person.location" required/> 
                    <span ng-show="personForm.location.$error.required" class="msg-val">Location is required.</span> </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td colspan="2"> <span ng-if="personCtrl.flag=='created'" class="msg-success">Person successfully added.</span>
                  <span ng-if="personCtrl.flag=='failed'" class="msg-val">Person already exists.</span> </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr><td colspan="2">
                     <div ng-if="personCtrl.flag != 'edit'">
                     <input  type="submit" ng-click="personCtrl.addPerson()" value="Add Person"/> 
                     <input type="button" ng-click="personCtrl.reset()" value="Reset"/>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="personCtrl.flag == 'edit'">
                    <input  type="submit" ng-click="personCtrl.updatePersonDetail()" value="Update Person"/>    
                     <input type="button" ng-click="personCtrl.cancelUpdate()" value="Cancel"/>                
                     </div> </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <td colspan="2"> <span ng-if="personCtrl.flag=='deleted'" class="msg-success">Person successfully deleted.</span>
                     </tr>
                    </table>     
                </form>
               <table>
              <tr><th>ID </th> <th>Name</th> <th>Location</th></tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="row in personCtrl.persons">
                <td><span ng-bind="row.pid"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.name"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.location"></span></td>
                 <td>
                 <input type="button" ng-click="personCtrl.deletePerson(row.pid)" value="Delete"/>
                   <input type="button" ng-click="personCtrl.editPerson(row.pid)" value="Edit"/>
                 <span ng-if="personCtrl.flag=='updated' && row.pid==personCtrl.updatedId" class="msg-success">Person successfully updated.</span> </td> 
                  </tr> 
               </table>
              </div>
            <%--    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
             <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
              <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/app.js"></script> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css"/>--%>

         </body>
        </html>
```

**appconfig.java**

```
package com.concretepage.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.concretepage")
@Import(DBConfig.class)
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/aresources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

**webappinitializer.java**

```
package com.concretepage.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

GET 
http://localhost:8081/springAngulerHibernate/aresources/css/style.css  404 error  while accessing resource .  so style.css not loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an extra `a` letter in your `mvc:resources`. instead of:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/aresources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

use this:

```
addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
```

**Try to be more consistent with your folder naming, is it resources? or is it aresources?**

Second, Use the Spring URL tag, in order to resolve your URL better.

Here is how I use to import bootstrap.min.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<spring:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>' type="text/css" />
```

Don't forget to add the taglib, like this:

Comment: Didnt worked i changed   
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

and used spring:url too

Comment: but you have to make sure that under webapp folder you have another folder name: `resources`   and inside it you need to have the files you're trying to load.

Comment: No problem, anytime. I would appreciate if you give me a vote up. tnx.